# how to check if button is pushed if the form in is one php file but its checked in another

Tags: php, html

I have two PHP files, lets call them fileOne.php and fileTwo.php. If fileOne.php has a form with `action="fileTwo.php"` and with the buttons button1 and button2, how do I check in fileTwo.php if `isset($_POST['button1'])` was pushed, or `isset($_POST['button2']` was pushed.

This is the form for "fileTwo.php" in "fileOne.php": (execute.php = fileTwo.php)

```
< form action="execute.php" method = "POST">
< input type="hidden" name="edit" value="Edit"/>
< input type="hidden" name="delete" value="Remove"/>
< /form>
```

These are the buttons that are created in "fileOne.php" but in the form action= "fileTwo.php" : ("button1 = edit, button2 = delete)

```
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='Edit' value='Edit'>
<input type='submit' name='Delete' value='Remove'></td>\n";
```

This is where I try to check in "fileTwo.php" if either button was pushed:

```
    //if edit is clicked
if(isset($_POST['edit'] == 'Edit'))
{
    echo"hello";
}
//if remove is clicked
if(isset($_POST['delete'] == 'Remove'))
{
    echo"good bye";
}
```

I would appreciate the solution in PHP, not JavaScript, AJAX, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make two forms:

```
< form action="execute.php" method = "POST">
< input type="hidden" name="delete" value="Remove"/>
< input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
< /form>

< form action="execute.php" method = "POST">
< input type="hidden" name="edit" value="Edit"/>
< input type="submit" value="Edit"/>
< /form>
```

in fileTwo.php:

```
//input names(edit, delete) and values(Edit, Remove) are case sensetive
if( isset($_POST['edit']) && $_POST['edit'] == 'Edit') {
    echo"hello";
}

//if remove is clicked
if( isset($_POST['delete']) && $_POST['delete'] == 'Remove') {
    echo"good bye";
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and it still does not work. Do I need the forms in both files? I tried it with both forms in both files, with both in the fileOne.php, and with just one form in both files. Thank you for the suggestion though

Comment: you cant submit the form using buttons outside the form, i thought you were using javascript until i read your question again. you need to add submit button to each form, also your issest code is incorrect isset($variable = "value") is wrong isset($variable) && $variable = "value" is correct. see my updated answer.

Comment: you dont need forms on the fileTwo.php

Comment: @razzak I wasn't the one who downvoted it but I would guess someone downvoted it because creating 2 forms isn't necessary to solve the problem and wouldn't scale well for cases where there were other fields on the form besides the buttons.

Comment: i know it was unnecessary to create two forms but i was trying to make it very simple for the OP. the voted answer is copied from my answer after merging the forms! but never mind.

Comment: @razzakL I down voted it. It’s totally and blatantly wrong. Not only are two forms unnecessary but you didn’t correct the syntax problems with the PHP code such as the double if statement and no spaces between operators and parameters. Also, OP stated it didn’t work.

Comment: i tested my code on my server before posting it and it is working 100%, and double if statement is a common practice and there's nothing wrong with it. it might not be the perfect answer but u didn't have to downvote it as it's correct answer and fixes the problem.

Comment: There were many more problems in my code that I was unaware of, which made this solution not work the first time I tried it. I ended up using two forms like you suggested. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite it like this:

*fileOne.php*

```
<form action="fileTwo.php" method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="edit" value="edit" />
   <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" />
</form>
```

*fileTwo.php*

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['edit']) && ($_POST['edit'] == 'edit')) {
    echo "Hello";
}
else if (isset($_POST['delete']) && ($_POST['delete'] == 'delete')) {
    echo "Goodbye";
}
?>
```

Ok, this way you don’t need any extra code, no hidden inputs and only 2 buttons. Both will submit your form with the values needed for the handler on the next page to deal with them correctly.